# How to paint notebook-like lines as TextBox background?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, customization

A bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807428/wpf-how-can-i-make-a-brush-that-paints-graph-paper-like-squares).

My aim is to evocate a notebook-like look of the textbox.

[image]

OneNote does something similar, by setting background image of the editing surface. Of course it is not possible to align the lines in OneNote because the text can be freely formatted.

I would like to do this with constant font (no formatting) in WPF. How to paint lines in textbox background that will match the lines of text?

Comment: @Jerry: No, I have not found a way how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question here: [Repeat a background brush in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083197/repeat-a-background-brush-in-wpf/7084840#7084840)

It would be easy to convert to a TextBox.

Best of luck!

Comment: I do not see how it solves my problem - the lines must match font height

Comment: It does, that was also my requirement. Look more closely. ;)