# Draw styled lines in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, customization

Is there any way to make lines between points, given a simple **geometry** as line style, using **WPF geometries**? I know it is possible to make these kind of lines:

```
-- -- --- --
```

But I want to make lines, using any simple geometry (e.g: the '^' symbol). So what I want is something like these: (the line may not necessarily be horizontal or vertical):

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
*****************
```

**Note:** I don't want to make line with some characters. I want to do it using any arbitrary geometries (e.g: start shape, triangle, or any other geometry). In other word I want to repeat some geometries along a linear path between two points. So these simple geometries may be rotated somehow to follow the line and ...

Comment: The output I'm looking for should be of geometry types. for example: `StreamGeometry`

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Windows.Shapes.Line` with a custom brush for the `Stroke` property?

Comment: I tried the `StrokeDashArray` but it didn't solve the problem. I make a `StreamGeometry` with the line data and then create a `Path` from them. Can you explain more how it is possible to use the custom brush in this case. (code sample will be helpful)

Comment: This might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807428/wpf-how-can-i-make-a-brush-that-paints-graph-paper-like-squares

Comment: Thanks, that a good link but for general lines (with arbitrary slope) it seems the brush must be somehow rotated! otherwise it will not draw the desired shape.

Comment: To rotate the brush simply calculate the angle (in degrees) of the line You want to draw with the brush, e.g. `double r = 180 * Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X) / Math.PI`, and then set the `Transform` property of Your brush to `new RotateTransform(-r)` (You need to use negative value of the angle because `RotateTransform` rotates clockwise). Should You need to also have other transforms on Your brush, use `TransformGroup` instead.

Comment: Have you tried using Image Brush (Tile Brush)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970682.aspx , also have a look at other brush How to at the same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an interesting problem but I can't fit a satisfying answer in the stackoverflow textbox so I uploaded a proposed solution on github:

https://github.com/mrange/CodeStack/tree/master/q14545675/LineGeometry

I don't claim this is 100% solution to your problem (for one I am not 100% of all your requirements) but if you take a look at it perhaps something can be worked and improved upon.

Unless ofc I am way wrong on what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I did update the code to avoid .Clone (potentially expensive) and TransformGroups (unnecessary). There might be performance improvments in using .DrawGeometry multiple times instead of building a single cached geometry.

Comment: Now uses a single cached drawing instead of geometry. Should be less complex to generate.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for others solutions (maybe some better ideas). Otherwise you may won the +50 :)

Comment: So what is a better idea in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to use the `*` or `^` or `!` as a line essentially.  Rather then use a normal solid, dash, dotted, and so on line you'd like to use physical characters?  But you'd like those characters to become a `Geometry` object.

You could do something like:

```
// Create a line of characters.
string lineString = "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^";

// Create Formatted Text, customize accordingly.
FormattedText formatText = new FormattedText(
     lineString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
     FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
     new Typeface("Arial"), 32, Brushes.Black);

// Set the Width and Height.
formatText.MaxTextWidth = 200;
formatText.MaxTextHeight = 100;

// You can obviously add as many customization's and outputs of your choice.
```

Now I understand this isn't what you want, you want the above `string` to act in `Geometry`.  To accomplish that; you just need to do:

```
// Build Geometry object to represent text.
Geometry lineGeometry = formatText.BuildGeometry(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

// Tailor Geometry object that represents our item.
Geometry hGeo = formatText.BuildHighlightGeometry(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
```

Now essentially you've built a `Geometry` object that represents "^^^^^^^^".

Hopefully I understood correctly, I don't know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to draw custom line between two Points (p1, p2). Moreover I'm not going to make lines with some characters. I want to be able to make line with any custom geometry shape. Of course this geometry shape may be similar to some characters

Comment: That is what my answer is doing; turning the `formatText` intoa Geometry shape. Is that not what you meant? Im slightly confused now, could you explain it differently please so I can better assist you?

Comment: In general imagine I have a small geometry (e.g: star shape), I want to make line between any two arbitrary points with those starts (or any other shape).

Comment: Okay, let me think a little bit.  Off the top of my head I think about `Camera Projection` based on your question.  Creating a projection plane that will span across your space. Then you simply input `Geometry` of your choice and model it accordingly.  I'll try and come up with a solution.

Comment: A link to my initial thought on your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx#cameras